# Problem with GridView and RowStyle

Tags: asp.net, gridview, css

I have a problem with an `<asp:GridView>`

Rows are too tight from each other so i want to give them a fixed height. I tried using RowStyle's and AlternatingRowStyle's cssclass. In my css I have:

```
.new_fila_exp_ini
{
    margin:0 auto 100px auto;
}
```

But it doesn't use the 100 pixels.

I think it's because it used to be a HTML table before that I converted into a `<asp:GridView>`  so the styles doesn't apply correctly.
But I don't know how to do it.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting margin on a table row won't work very well, you're better off setting padding. In order to do that more effectively, set the padding on each table cell, like:

```
.new_fila_exp_ini td {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

See how you get on with that.